# optimize build time of iOS projects with large database

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am developing an app which itself is small (~20m) and builds fast on the simulator, but comes with a large database (~800m) and takes a long time to build on a device. It seems the majority of time is spent on copying(verifying) files in the database which never change. Is there a way to reduce/skip this step and accelerate the build?

Comment: Could you database be prepared at build time rather than run time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe while testing you could put the database in the `Documents` folder and copy it through iTunes or drop the files in the right folder on the simulator.

I think that way Xcode won't need to copy the file to the device, but of course it makes for a slightly more complex setup on the first run.